# Google Assistant Permission denied for your request

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, chatbot

Why when I want to try an Dialogflow's intent in Google Assistant, I get the message "Permission denied for your request"?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your problem might be without further details. [Please update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58795790/edit) with more information about what, exactly, you're doing that is causing this problem. Including screen shots of you trying, the error message, etc could be very helpful. See [How Do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further tips.

Comment: Yes, we need to know what exactly you are doing... Like you are using the the tester web app? Sending the payload directly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.  Your first step may be to make sure that you are using the same account (i.e. gmail account) on Dialogflow that you used to make your project on your Actions Consoles

I am signed into multiple gmail accounts and only noticed that my Actions Console was signed into one account and my Dialogflow was signed into a different account.  When I made sure both Actions Console and Dialogflow were signed into the same account, I was able to run my test.